# Notice on retrieving and handling

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table:

[image]

I want a query that will retrieve the maximum QID from the table where I specify a Pid. Then I want to take the selected value and add 1 to it. I want this to work even if there is no value on qid where Pid is for example 1 or 2.

For example if the max qid is 1 where pid is 1, I want a code to retrieve the value qid=1 and add 1 to it. Then the new value, "2" in this case, should be stored in a hidden input field. If I, for example, put "WHERE pid=4" in my query and there is no pid=4 in my table, which retrieves a null value from qid, that should also work and the new value should be 1(null + 1 = 1).

I have this but I don't know if it is right. I'm maybe doing something wrong in the query.

```html
<?php
$qu = "SELECT coalesce(max(qid),1) AS id FROM answer_det WHERE pid = '1' ";
 $result = $mysqli->query($qu);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {   
        
        echo "
            <form action='insertdilemma.php' method='post'>
            <input type='text' name='ans1'>
            <input type='hidden' name='qidsend' value='". $row["id"]. "'>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send'>   
            </form>";
}}
  else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
       
?>
```

I get this error message: 
**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wildfire\dilemman.php on line 132**

This is on line 132: **if ($result->num_rows > 0) {**

Comment: Your query failed because of an obvious syntax error

Comment: There are two `WHERE` in your query.

Comment: Your query says `WHERE WHERE`... erase one of those.

Comment: Oh my God... I'm editing this now!!

Comment: In the future try, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php.

Comment: I will update you if something is still wrong! Big sorry!

Comment: @John Conde Yes fixed this now, but this only removed the notice. Now everything looks fine on the page, but the purpose isn't working. That is to check the max qid where I choose a specific pid and add 1 to it. I always get the value 1 as output, the adding functiong doesn't work.

Comment: Does executing `SELECT max(qid) AS id FROM answer_det WHERE WHERE pid = '1'` give you a result; in DB, or in code?

Comment: @chris85 I'm collecting the maximum QID from a table in my database. I'm not sure if I understood your question but I hope I did.

Comment: If you execute the query on the db interface (phpmyadmin maybe) does it give you the expected result?

Comment: @chris85 The result is then the latest qid, lets say 1. It doesn't take the latest qid and add 1 to it. The latest id stays as it is. I want to add 1 to it and then use the new value, let say as a variable for example.

Comment: Then you don't want your `where` clause at all. You just want the highest `qid` in the table, right? Sounds like maybe you should just make that column auto-incrementing..

Comment: @chris85 No, I really need to select the max qid from where I choose a specific pid. Maybe I could just select the latest qid and store it in a variable and then take the variable and + 1 to it and then have that as a new variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply remove the second where

```
   $qu = "SELECT ifnull(max(qid)+1,1) AS id FROM answer_det  WHERE pid = '1' ";
```

and you should submit the new qid but also the id .

```
    echo "
        <form action='insertdilemma.php' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='ans1'>
        <input type='hidden' name='pidsend' value='". $row["pid"]. "'>
        <input type='hidden' name='qidsend' value='". $row["id"]. "'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send'>   
        </form>";
```

Comment: Yes I did this, but this only removed the notice. Now everything looks fine on the page, but the purpose isn't working. That is to check the max qid where I choose a specific pid and add 1 to it. I always get the value 1, the adding functiong doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you save a valid result in db? And second why you use pid='1' and not  pid = '$your_var_pid'?

Comment: I have update the asnwer . i think you don't sent pid (not only qid/id)

Comment: I use WHERE pid = '$pid3' in my code but I wanted to show a simple code in my question, which is the reason. I got a new idea; maybe I could just select the max qid and store it in a variable. Then take the variable and + 1 to it and then have that as a new variable? Then only have the latest variable as a value in a hidden input field? How would the code for that look like?

Comment: And why do you send the pid when I only need to send the max qid+1?

Comment: That should work even if the max qid is null. Then I should have null + 1, which then is 1 and that should be my new qid.

Comment: You should store pid , qid (and question_link ) otherwise how you can correctly solve the query?

Comment: I have this code and this one proceeds the pid: <input type='hidden' name='pid4' value='$pid3'>

Comment: Why you use coalesce(max(qid),1) and not coalesce(max(qid)+1,1) like suggested in a previous similar question and i answer with ifnull(max(qid)+1,1) the mean of the +1 is evident .. also if you don't like ifnull..

Comment: Two questions. If I would only like to have a query that picks the max qid WHERE pid = '$pid3' even if the value is null, how would that query look like? I would store that value in a hidden text field, which I would retrieve in the second page and store into a variable, lets say "$retrieved". Then I could maybe create a new variable which would be : $retrievednew = "$retrieved + 1"; . I think that it would work?

Comment: In coalesce(max(qid)+1,1) , what does the second "1" do there?

Comment: Try using ifnull(max(qid)+1,1) instead of coalesce.. i have update the answer.  coalese. give you only max(qid) or 1,   ifnull give you max(qid)+1, and 1.  .. i think is what you are looking for..